# Regex grouping only returning one group

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have the following text and I need the regex to return multiple groups not just the first match...everything I've tried always just returns the first group...

```
\[\s*(?<g1>(?i:Critical|Urgent)):\s*(?<g2>.+)\]
```

Example:

```
lorem ipsum [Urgent: do something] lorem ipsum [Critical: do something else] lorem ipsum
```

Ideally g1 would contain ['Urgent','Critical'] and g2 would contain ['do something','do something else']

Answer (score 0):

[This regex](http://regexr.com/3acra) will have two matches, each with two groups.

`\[(Critical|Urgent):\s?(.*?)\]`

With http://regexr.com/ you can test regexes online. It's great for learning why they don't work too as you can put your cursor on every part of your regex and see what it does.